# Azure - Publish Web API - Compile

Tags: azure, asp.net-web-api, azure-devops, azure-pipelines, release

I'm trying to use a DevOps pipeline to deploy a Web API. I've got it working, looks great.

*However*, when the files are copied for the artifact, all of the source files are there too. When I use Visual Studio to "Publish" my Web API, there are minimal files, single Web.config (not Web.Release.config, Web.Debug.config)

Is there a way I can achieve this or, do I run a clean-up script to bin off the files I don't want there.

Example - published with Visual Studio:
[image: Published with Visual Studio]

Example - published with Azure:
[image: Published with Azure]

**Edit**:
Created  task group which goes through and deletes the unnecessary files and directories - not sure this is the correct approach but it does work.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you know, First of all you should publish your source on Azure
e.g.

```
- task: UseDotNet@2
  inputs:
    packageType: 'sdk'
    version: '3.1.x'
- script: dotnet publish --self-contained -r win-x64
  displayName: 'dotnet build $(buildConfiguration)'
```

Then use your published files for your artifact.
e.g.

```
bin/Debug/netcoreapp3.1/win-x64/publish
```

You don't need to remove anything for this purpose.